# database import via CMD seem to freeze

Tags: mysql

So I got curious and also wanted to mess around with a larger database so I downloaded the AM database dump and went on my merry way to import it into a wamp-server mysql. The first, and biggest dump file went without a hitch (took about 30 mins but worked). Btw, I am porting these via cmd - mysql.exe -u root -p am-users <"FILELOCATION"\filename.dump to avoid phpMyAdmin's max file size.

However, every other dump-file starts importing fine, but then never finishes importing. It‘s still doing something as I can see mysqld.exe using varying CPU percentages (always around 20% with an i5 3540k), disk writing and memory usages through the task manager, but it just never finishes.

Has anyone else experienced something similar and did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently for some reason some loads into the mysql db take longer than others. The 9 gig file took roughly 30 mins. The 3 gig file took about 2h. I don't know why this is the way it is but it appears to be just the way it is.

Comment: You can log into MySQL (or phpMyAdmin) and issue a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see what the database server is doing.